# Save existing project to an external drive Final Cut Pro X 10

Tags: video, software, file-formats, final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

I have a project with events saved on my Mac drive. I want to save this project on my external HD drive to clean space and work on this project later.

I copy pasted Final Cut Events and Final Cut Projects folders to my external HD but I don't know how to restore it into project in FC.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well I doubt you can run strait off of the drive. Is it OK if you copy it over to your computer again then back to a drive? Most software does not like reading off of drives.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "most software" but most software has absolutely no problem reading off of external drives

Comment: Remember to manually copy and custom transitions, lower thirds, Motion assets, etc. as they don't come over by default in a Move or Duplicate Project procedure.

Comment: If your external drive is actually hooked up but it still doesn't show up and you get the message "no value", do a "get info" on the drive and check the "ignore permissions" box on the bottom left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I copy pasted Final Cut Events and Final Cut Projects folders to my external HD but I don't know how to restore it into project in FC. Any help is appreciated."

It's better to perform this type of operation from within FCPX, instead of the Finder via copy/paste.  With the project selected in the Project Library, choose File->Move Project...  As long as you have an external drive connected, the resultant "location" dropdown menu will be populated (instead of saying "no value").  Selecting the "Move project and referenced events" radio button will transfer all of the necessary media to the external drive, AND remove it from the local drive, thus freeing up space.

When you work this way, there is no need to, as you say, "restore it to a project in FC".  You simply make sure the external drive which contains the project file and media is connected to your machine, and the project is available in the project library window.